# boost::asio usage in self-contained class

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

Trying to get my head around the boost classes.  What I want to do, differs from the [boost asio tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp) in that, the tutorial has a main() where the io_service object is instantiated.  That is then passed to the class implementing asio via its constructor.

What I want to do, is to eliminate the instantiation of io_service in the main and have the implementing class be "self-contained" in that, it will declare its own io_service and socket.  I must be reading the example with tunnel-vision, because I cannot figure out how to drop the instantiation of io_service into my socket class.

At first, I was getting "error C2758: 'xxx::io_service' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list".  So, I thought I'd do that and added "io_service(new boost::asio::io_service()), socket(io_service)" to the class initializer list.  That gave me "error C2354: 'xxx::io_service' : initialization of reference member requires a temporary variable", which, after some googling, made sense.

So, my question is, how can I adjust the tutorial code to eliminate the main()?

Comment: Post the code in your class instead of describing your problem! My guess is you still have `io_service` defined as a reference, and it shouldn't be.

Comment: main is just a function.  You can create a function that is called from main that does the exact same work.

Comment: @Praetorian nailed it.  Changed that and remove the initializer and my build is now on to other errors.  :)  Tunnel-vision.

Comment: Seriously?  A downvote?  Sigh.

Comment: @Jon In my humble opinion your question is very poor, more of a rant than anything else. To add insult to injury the "war stories" you recount show you lack understanding of basic aspects of the C++ language. I didn't downvote, but I guess that explains it.

Comment: I intended no rant or telling of "war stories", was just trying to ask what I thought was a clear question.  In the end, I simply missed adjusting an existing class reference variable.  As I said, I was reading the boost tutorial (first time using boost) and was reading the code with "tunnel vision", where you focus on the issue rather than looking more broadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after:

Move the io_service into the class (not by reference). And all usages as well.

I opted to put the join into the destructor.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include "chat_message.hpp"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

typedef std::deque<chat_message> chat_message_queue;

class chat_client
{
public:
  chat_client(std::string host, std::string portorservice)
    : io_service_(),
      thread_(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_)),
      socket_(io_service_)
  {
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
    tcp::resolver::query query(host, portorservice);
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, iterator,
        boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_connect, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void write(const chat_message& msg)
  {
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_write, this, msg));
  }

  void close()
  {
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_close, this));
  }

  ~chat_client() {
    close();
    if (thread_.joinable())
        thread_.join();
  }

private:

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
  }

  void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error && read_msg_.decode_header())
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length()),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_body, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }

  void handle_read_body(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      std::cout.write(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length());
      std::cout << "\n";
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }

  void do_write(chat_message msg)
  {
    bool write_in_progress = !write_msgs_.empty();
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    if (!write_in_progress)
    {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
            write_msgs_.front().length()),
          boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      write_msgs_.pop_front();
      if (!write_msgs_.empty())
      {
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
              write_msgs_.front().length()),
            boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_write, this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }
    }
    else
    {
      do_close();
    }
  }

  void do_close()
  {
    socket_.close();
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
  boost::thread thread_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
  chat_message read_msg_;
  chat_message_queue write_msgs_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: chat_client <host> <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        chat_client c(argv[1], argv[2]);

        char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];
        while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
        {
            using namespace std; // For strlen and memcpy.
            chat_message msg;
            msg.body_length(strlen(line));
            memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
            msg.encode_header();
            c.write(msg);
        }

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```